# How do I get all messages from a FB conversation?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tornado

I want to get all messages of a facebook conversation. This conversation has around 60,000 messages and I want to get all of them. Is possible to get all of them in one go or I have to make multiple requests with pagination?

The [Thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/) documentation is of hardly any help. I registered an app and using the access key in the Graph API Explorer. Even if I change the the limit to 25000 still I am getting handful of messages.

```
t_id.<thread_id>/messages?limit=25000
```

So what's the best way to get all messages?

I will be using this in my tornado app. The call would be something like this:

```
    self.facebook_request("/53......13", access_token=self.get_secure_cookie('access_token'), callback=self.async_callback(self._after_messages))
```

Comment: Pagination it is. Facebook policy says "You will only request the data you need to operate your application". They discourage warehousing of data by its application developers.